# How Can I Get The Overflow Scroll Position To Start In The Middle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, frontend

I'm really trying to get the overflow-x scrollbar scroll position to start in the middle instead of to to the left:

[image]

Currently, it always starts at the left side:
[image]

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell what you're doing currently without seeing some code, but it sounds like you need to dynamically set the position of the scrollbar based on the page  width when it's initially loaded. In Vue, try wrapping your content in a `div` container and setting the `scrollLeft` property of the element in your `mounted()` function.

Here's a codepen of what that logic might look like:

**Snippet**

Link: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Brett-H/pen/YzBWmqE)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const scrollContainer = document.getElementById('scroll-container');
  const content = document.getElementById('content');
  
  const middlePosition = (content.offsetWidth - scrollContainer.clientWidth) / 2;
 
  scrollContainer.scrollLeft = middlePosition;
});
```

```css
#scroll-container {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container" id="scroll-container">
  <div class="content" id="content">
  </div>
</div>
```